# Visual C++ 2010 Console Application dwFontSize values?

Tags: c++, winapi, fonts

```
void setFontSize()
{
     HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
     PCONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX lpConsoleCurrentFontEx = new CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX();
     lpConsoleCurrentFontEx->cbSize = sizeof(CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX);
     GetCurrentConsoleFontEx(hConsole, 0 , lpConsoleCurrentFontEx);
     lpConsoleCurrentFontEx->dwFontSize.X = 8;
     lpConsoleCurrentFontEx->dwFontSize.Y = 16;
     SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(hConsole, 0, lpConsoleCurrentFontEx);
}
```

I'm doing changing the font size in the Console. I'm having some problems with the dimensions of `dwFontSize.X` and `dwFontSize.Y`. I want the size very big. What values are known to work? Does it follow some kind of pattern? Because if I insert something that's clearly not acceptable it uses the default. Or is it easier to change the font type to Lucida Console and its size instead of the default Raster Font? In that case, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you open a DOS prompt (Start -> Run -> cmd.exe), left-click on the window icon, choose **Properties**, and click the **Font** tab, you can see which fonts / sizes are supported.

[image]

Comment: Yes, that was the first thing I did. The thing is, I used a bigger size that wasn't in the list and it worked. But as I said, I want it reeeaalllyyy big. Like Lucida's 72px.

Answer (score 0):

The raster fonts don't scale.  If you want to set an arbitrary size, then you need to change to a font that can scale (like Consolas or Lucida Console) and then change the size.  To select a particular font, specify the font name in the FaceName field of the CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX.